# PHP file_get_contents and VAST xml

Tags: php, xml, vast

This is what am I trying to do: download a xml VAST from a URL and save locally in a XML file, in PHP. For that I am using file_get_contents and file_put_contents. this is the script I am using:

```
<?php
$tid=time();

$xml1 = file_get_contents('http://ad.afy11.net/ad?enc=4&asId=1000009566807&sf=0&ct=256');
file_put_contents("downloads/file1_$tid.xml", $xml1);
echo "<p>file 1 recorded</p>";
?>
```

The URL in question is a real URL that will deliver a xml VAST code. My problem is that when I save de file it will write an empty VAST tag:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <VAST version="2.0"> </VAST>
```

But if I run on Firefox it will actually deliver some code:

```
<VAST version="2.0"><Ad id="Adify"><Wrapper><AdSystem>Eyeblaster</AdSystem><VASTAdTagURI>http://bs.serving-sys.com/BurstingPipe/adServer.bs?cn=is&c=23&pl=VAST&pli=6583370&PluID=0&pos=7070&ord=4288438534]&cim=1</VASTAdTagURI><Impression>http://ad.afy11.net/ad?ipc=NMUsqYdyBUCjh4-i2HwWfK1oILM2AAAAN6-rBkSy8JNMZcuzAlj1XlSySpo6Hi7xEYULS+UgOVN5D3UuhFUVSWbFHoLE-+3su0-QnGgZgMJyiTm-R6O+yQ==</Impression><Creatives/></Wrapper></Ad></VAST>
```

Not a 100% of the time, they do cap the amount of requests, but WAY more often that when I try save the file using the PHP script.

Is that a way to make the PHP script mimic a browser???? I dont know if this is the right question but thats the only thing I can think of why I get an empty VAST tag when using the php script and get a full tag when using the browser.

any ideas???

thanks :)

Update: After doing some extra research, I found some info about stream_context_create function, but I haven't been able to duplicate the browser's results.

here's my new code:

```
<?php

$tid=time();

$opts = array('http' =>
    array(
        'method'  => 'GET',
        //'user_agent '  => "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-US; rv:1.9.2) Gecko/20100301 Ubuntu/9.10 (karmic) Firefox/3.6",
        'header' => array(
            'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*\/*;q=0.8
'
        ), 
    )
);
$context  = stream_context_create($opts);


$xml1 = file_get_contents('http://ad.afy11.net/ad?enc=4&asId=1000009566807&sf=0&ct=256');
file_put_contents("downloads/file1_$tid.xml", $xml1);
echo "<p>file 1 recorded</p>";
echo "<textarea rows='6' cols='80'> $xml1 </textarea> ";
echo "<br><iframe src='http://ad.afy11.net/ad?enc=4&asId=1000009566807&sf=0&ct=256' width='960' height='300'></iframe>";
?>
```

I also addded a iframe to compare when the browser are getting the right file and when the php function are not.

Comment: Please contact the vendor of this service for your support options.

Comment: It is not about the vendor, it is about figure out what file_get_contents are doing differently that firefox.

Comment: Well, that is easy to say: all and nothing. All in the sense that this function is totally different to firefox. Nothing because even when I open this URL in the browser I get that what file_get_contents get. This is why it is better to contact the vendor of those webservices for first-level support so to get into the know how requests need to be performed, when such things change and so on and so forth.

Comment: Thank again but I still say there is nothing wrong with the vendor. I tested here the url, as I said before, when you load the url on firefox it will load 19 out of 20, when I load with file_get_contents it will load 0 out of 100. the url is generated by an server, that might be looking the requests and ignoring the one made with file_get_contents. Im your case might be the same thing, where are you located??? anyhow All I think I need is to make file_get_contents behaves just like firefox to the server and I am sure I will start getting results.

Comment: Obviously as your sightings show, there are differences between the two (which I didn't neglect, I wrote already before that both firefox and filegetcontents are absolutely different). You contact the vendor just for the case to learn from him which specification exactly needs to be matched to obtain those files. As far as you're concerned in my findings, I was not able to use in chrome (not firefox) the URL in question in 0 out of 100 like with your filegetcontents description. So never a 19 out of 20 for me with a browser.

Comment: Also if there is a 19 out of 20, there also is a 5 out of 100 for firefox as well when it behaves like filegetcontents. It seems there is a lot more to reverse engineer the network traffic to obtain something close to the specification if you do not want to contact the vendor for that specification. Just saying it does not work says really not much, there can be a thousand issues that cause this and you need to troubleshoot here as you seem to be the only person who can successfully perform these requests with an internet browser.

Comment: the requests are based in geo location and requests distribution, thats why I asked where are you, to confirm. but again, thank you for your time. I will keep looking for a answer

Comment: So do you want to say you are passing geolocation information with the request when you request with firefox? If so, how? AFAIK this only works with javascript.

Comment: Also regarding my location it's europe - that is also in my profile. Sorry for not mentioning this earlier, didn't see. If you've got IP based geolocation checks, it's probably possible to pass-on a different IP with faking proxy headers.

Comment: I also fail to look your profile. thats why you cant see the content from the url.

Answer (score 4):

After some research I found a solution for my problem, and I would like to share here for future reference.
The idea as to pass some HTTP header with the file_get_contents. I accomplish that with this:

```
$opts = array(
            'http'=>array(
                        'method'=>"GET",
                        'header'=>array("Accept-language: en", "Content-Type: multipart/form-data\r\n"),
                        'user_agent'=>    $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']
                        )
            );

$context = stream_context_create($opts); 

$xml4 = file_get_contents($url1, true, $context);
```

That's it, now I can get the same xml as if I was using the browser.

Comment: Isn't that awesome when you have the same question, 3 years later, and you find your own answer and still works :)